# Discord.js bot - music function: 'Invalid argument type' --Cannot identify issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm working on a discord.js bot that plays music. The idea is that a user can type "X play" (X being the prefix for the bot) to get the bot to join the voice channel that the commander is in. Or, the user can type "X play [YouTube Link]" to play the audio from a YouTube video using YTDL. So far, The bot can join the channel fine. However, when i attach a link i am returned with a very complicated error that i simply don't understand at all. I've referred to documentations and help forums but there is nothing relating to my issue. I've attached the module for the command.

```
const Commando = require('discord.js-commando');
const YTDL = require('ytdl-core');

function Play(connection, message)
{
    var server = servers[message.guild.id];
    server.dispatcher = connection.playStream(YTDL(server.queue[0], {filter: "audioonly"}));
    server.queue.shift();
    server.dispatcher.on("end", function(){
        if(server.queue[0])
        {
            Play(connection, message);
        }
        else
        {
            connection.disconnect();
        }
    });

}

class JoinChannelCommand extends Commando.Command
{
    constructor(client)
    {
        super(client,{
            name: 'play',
            group: 'simple',
            memberName: 'play',
            description: 'Plays the audio from a youtube link'
        });
    }

    async run(message, args)
    {
        if(message.member.voiceChannel)
        {
            if(!message.guild.voiceConnection)
            {
                if(!servers[message.guild.id])
                {
                    servers[message.guild.id] = {queue: []}
                }
                message.member.voiceChannel.join()
                    .then(connection =>{
                        var server = servers[message.guild.id];
                        message.reply("Successfully joined!");
                        server.queue.push(args);
                        Play(connection, message);
                    })
            }
        }
        else
        {
            message.reply("ERROR: Not connected to voice channel");
        }
    }
}

module.exports = JoinChannelCommand;
```

When i type "X play" the bot joins the channel. When i type "X play [link]", the bot joins but doesn't play music. The console returns:

```
(node:5136) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "file" argument must be of type string. Received type object
    at validateString (internal/validators.js:125:11)
    at normalizeSpawnArguments (child_process.js:414:3)
    at Object.spawn (child_process.js:553:16)
    at new FfmpegProcess (C:\My Discord Bots\XyloBot\node_modules\prism-media\src\transcoders\ffmpeg\FfmpegProcess.js:14:33)
    at FfmpegTranscoder.transcode (C:\My Discord Bots\XyloBot\node_modules\prism-media\src\transcoders\ffmpeg\Ffmpeg.js:34:18)
    at MediaTranscoder.transcode (C:\My Discord Bots\XyloBot\node_modules\prism-media\src\transcoders\MediaTranscoder.js:27:31)
    at Prism.transcode (C:\My Discord Bots\XyloBot\node_modules\prism-media\src\Prism.js:13:28)
    at AudioPlayer.playUnknownStream (C:\My Discord Bots\XyloBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\voice\player\AudioPlayer.js:97:35)
    at VoiceConnection.playStream (C:\My Discord Bots\XyloBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\voice\VoiceConnection.js:478:24)
    at Play (C:\My Discord Bots\XyloBot\commands\music\join.js:7:36)
(node:5136) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:5136) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Apologies for the long segments of code etc, however this is far out of my reach. Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you console.log the value of `args` at this line `server.queue.push(args);`? It should be a string for the `connection.playStream` to work

Comment: @T. Dirks, I added `console.log(args);` underneath `server.queue.puch(args);` and sure enough, it simply returns the youtube link. The argument should be string however it appears not to be.

Comment: Does it log like: `['youtube link']` or like `youtube link`

Comment: It sends the link and only the link:
`https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p4902jZecQE`
on its own with nothing else